# Chaining Read-Writes with Office-JS

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, office-js

I am having a problem working out how to chain syncs in Office JS - I think I have to do one sync to read the values then another sync to write them back - must be simple but I can't find a chaining example.

Basically I am trying to code the equivalent of this VBA code which does a read and a write via an array

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
d1 = MicroTimer
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D1000")
var = rng1.Value2
rng2.Value2 = var
d2 = (MicroTimer - d1) * 1000

MsgBox d2
```

or even simpler

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D1000").Value2=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000").Value2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the values from one range to another, you can use the following code:

```
Excel.run(function(context) {
    var range1 = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("A1:A1000").load('values');
    return context.sync()
        .then(() => {
            var range2 = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("D1:D1000");
            range2.values = range1.values;
            return context.sync();
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jakob - that looks simple enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Range-Class OfficeJS gives you.
Here is the full doc: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range (Also have a look at the examples given there)

To copy the Range, you need to create both ranges and copy the `.values[][]` from the source to the dest.

For how to copy a two-dimensional array (in this case: `values[][]`), you should use google.

To Determine the time, you can use the `Date()`-Class Java gives you.

Comment: yes I know how to do that: but it does not tell me how to chain a write following a read using Sync: all the examples only use a single Sync and Office JS does not seem to allow a read and a write within a single sync block